# Azure SQL Database is showing "Could not find stored procedure" with tedious while calling stored procedure

Tags: azure, tedious

While working with Azure SQL Database using `tedious` in Node.js.

It's throwing an error:

> Could not find stored procedure.

But the same code is working in SQL Server.

expected : `select the result from table`

But I Got that error.

Comment: adding sample code

var connection = new Connection({
 server: "server",
 options: { encrypt: true },
 authentication: {
 type: "default",
 options: {
  userName: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
  port:     "1433"
  }
 }
});
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
 var request = new Request('spname',
   function(err) {
  if (err) {
  }
  connection.close();
   });
 request.addParameter('id', TYPES.Int, 'custid');
 request.on('returnValue', function(paramName, value, metadata) {
 });
 connection.callProcedure(request);
});